# NServiceBus 4 and DTC

Tags: nservicebus, msdtc, nservicebus3, nservicebus4

I am looking at upgrading our NServiceBus 3.3.3 system to version 4.

**I read a few posts that seem to indicate that version 4 can work without DTC.  Is this true?**

Basically, this is what I am considering doing:

1. Changing my handlers to be able to deal with duplicate messages
2. Upgrading to Version 4 of NServiceBus
3. Turning off DTC on my database

From what I have read, I should be able to do this and not lose any messages.  (I work for a medical company and **losing a message means we lose a patient's data (very very bad)**.)

The only other thing of note is that my system runs with a distributor that then gives work to several workers.  The message through put is massive, (I am hopping that removing DTC will improve throughput).

**As a side note, would this be any different if I switched from MSMQ to RabbitMQ?**

Comment: This looks like an old question, but if you turn off DTC in v3, you are likely going to be okay if you implement you're own error handler using IMutateIncomingTransportMessages.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this in your configuration of the host:

```cs
Configure.Transactions.Disable();
```

But remember to handle all your errors properly and rollback any opened transactions manually.